# Appending the contents of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iFrame loaded from a url: The url points to a well formed piece of html; This loads ok.

[edit] There are no X domain issues etc.

```
 $("#targetIframe").attr("src", url);
```

How do I append say the `<head>` of the content just loaded into the iFrame ?
The line I'm using below doesn't seem to work

```
$("#targetIframe").find("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9090/html/flows/header.css">');
```

Do I have to wait in a timer before calling the append ?

Comment: Is the `url` you're providing on the same domain as the parent window? If not then you won't be able to inject any content as it would be a security breach.

Comment: yes it's on the same domain, no Xdomain issue etc

Comment: check browser console

Comment: In that case try `$('#targetIframe').contents().find('head').append(...`

Comment: No, that doesn't work. The head is found but there's no append

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  wait on a timer

```
$("#targetIframe").attr("src", url);

 setTimeout(function(){
        $("#targetIframe").find("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9090/html/flows/header.css">');
 }, 100);
```